# Why are nested loops chosen causing long execution time for "self join"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

*Disclaimer: this is not a question of what to do to improve performance, but rather why is it bad in first place.*

This following query is actually an essence of some bigger query, but small enough to demonstrate the issue I do not understand.

The tables involved are (skipping columns which are - I hope - irrelevant):

```
create table StanyJednostek (JednostkaID nchar(5), IndeksID nchar(18),
primary key (JednostkaID, IndeksID))

create table Jednostki (JednostkaID nchar(5),
primary key (JednostkaID))
```

`StanyJednostek` contains 29187 rows, while there are 1676 distinct `IndeksID` values in this table). `Jednostki` contains 94 rows.

And now, this query takes over two minutes to complete:

```
select
    StanyJednostek.JednostkaID, StanyJednostek.IndeksID
from StanyJednostek
    inner join
        (select distinct IndeksID from StanyJednostek) as Zmiany
        on StanyJednostek.IndeksID = Zmiany.IndeksID 
    inner join
        Jednostki on StanyJednostek.JednostkaID = Jednostki.JednostkaID
```

Here is execution plan:

[image]

What bothers me is this huge number of actual rows: 607147974. This obviously takes two minutes to complete. While I understand where this number comes from (this is 29187 times 20802, and 20802 is number of successful joins between `StanyJednostek` and `Jednostki`), I do not quite get why does query optimizer decide to choose nested loops here? Why is not `Zmiany` some kind of temporary set that is iterated over instead of the whole source table? What's also interesting is that while last two lines of the query seems irrelevant, if I remove those lines, execution plan changes and nested loops are replaced with hashes:

```
select
    StanyJednostek.JednostkaID, StanyJednostek.IndeksID
from StanyJednostek
    inner join
        (select distinct IndeksID from StanyJednostek) as Zmiany
        on StanyJednostek.IndeksID = Zmiany.IndeksID
```

Note that query optimizer also stops suggesting creating additional index on `IndeksID` in `StanyJednostek`.

[image]

Using `HASH` hint on *either* join leads to the following execution plan:

[image]

Comment: There's a Stream Aggregate operator on your first execution plan, but I don't see any aggregate function in your query. Are you sure it's the complete query?

Comment: Yes. These are complete queries.

Comment: What happens if you change the second join to `INNER HASH JOIN`? That will force a hash join, see if performance improves.

Comment: Yes, I tried this already. Actually hinting hash on *either* join causes hash to be used on both actually. This improves performance, but I am rather curious as stated in question: why is hash not chosen in first place.

Comment: @ZoffDino, why is second join so important that you suggested using hash on it in first place?

Comment: Never mind, that was a misguided attempt at the problem. See my answer below.

Comment: Usually SQL Server chooses ineffient execution plans due to poor estimates. In the first execution plan, what are estimate rows and actual rows on the output of both nested loops operators? Also SQL Server before SQL Server 2014 "thinks" inner joins filters things, but usually doesn't

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SQL Server reorders the joins to what it thinks is most efficient. In this case, it guesses wrong. Notice from your first execution plan that the join order is as follows:

```
StanyJednostek
INNER JOIN Jednostki 
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT IndeksID FROM StanyJednostek)
```

The first join is hardly anything to write home about - 29187 to 94 rows is not a problem. But the Query Optimizer guessed wrong about the result set from this join. It thinks this temporary result set only has 1 row.

Consequently, it picks a Nested Loop and thought it would scan `StanyJednostek` only one (*Estimated Number of Execution = 1*). In reality, it would scan `StanyJednostek` 20,802 times (the number of rows in the first result set, see *Number of Executions*).

Note that the `DISTINCT` operator is no where to be found yet. It is applied after both joins have been executed. Of course, by then you are dealing with 607,147,974 rows.

Since `IndeksID` is part of a composite primary key (and not the left-most key either), SQL Server does not keep detailed stats on it alone. Hence the index suggestion.

**Edit:**

1. **Is this wrong guess due to some out of date statistics?** Not likely. The first join matches on `JednostkaID`. See how the column appears in the PK of both tables. SQL Server may think that because it is in the PKs, it must be unique. This is likely a bug in the Query Optimizer.
2. **Why is SQL Server hoisting the `DISTINCT` operator?** From its guess, it saw that the `DISTINCT` operator will be applied to 20,802 rows, before or after the join - there's no difference! So my guess is that it just picks one.

**Some optimization suggestions:**

1. The `SELECT DISTINCT IndeksID` subquery is not needed, at all! This probably brings the biggest improvement to performance.
2. If you really insist on keeping the `SELECT DISTINCT` for some reason that is not in this question, I would recommend materialize it into a temp table. It forces SQL Server to apply `DISTINCT` on a smaller set of rows (29,187)
3. You can force the join order by adding `OPTION (FORCE ORDER)` to the end of the query. But use this carefully and sparingly.
4. You can force a has join by `INNER HASH JOIN`, but again, be mindful of the unwanted effect that aren't immediately visible. Any kind of query hint carries risks.

Comment: Thanks! Is this wrong guess (1 vs 20802 executions) due to some out of date statistics? What can be the reason for this? Is see the `DISTINCT` operator is applied after both joins indeed (this is this *Stream Aggregate*?) but why is that so? Of course I'll be glad for any suggestions to optimize the query.

Comment: OK, I see the query optimizer is somehow "hoisting" this `DISTINCT` operator, so probably according to relational theory it is allowed to do so, but as for now I do not yet understand why. :-)

Comment: I've created index on `IndeksID`. It changed the plan in a way that nested loop runs over this index, but huge difference between estimated and actual execution remains.

Comment: Yes, this `DISTINCT` is necessary as you guessed - in full version of the query there is actually only some subset of `IndeksID` in `StanyJednostek` involved - based on condition on unmentioned columns - but all rows related to those `IndeksID` are required - thus self join. Is there any hint to force SQL Server to apply `DISTINCT` to the subquery without introduction of temporary table? I tried CTE but no luck (it behaves exactly the same).

Comment: A `FORCE ORDER` may help you here.

Comment: BTW thank you for explanation. I definitely need to grasp query optimization better. If there is any course/book you would recommend I'd be glad to know.

Comment: I recommend first learning to read the execution plan. You can find more info in this question, including free eBooks in the linked articles: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758912/how-to-read-an-execution-plan-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

The second inner join expands the number of rows, since `StanyJednostek.JednostkaID = Jednostki.JednostkaID` is N:1. This increases the memory required by the hash join to above your system available, hence the hash join cannot be used.

As for why the missing index hint is gone: because a hash join does not need it. Is very likely that the missing index would improve perf.

Comment: I do not understand. The second join actually *decreases* number of rows involved doesn't it? I mean for each row in `StanyJednostek` there is only no more than one row in `Jednostki`. Or I understand you incorrectly?

Comment: "This increases the memory required by the hash join to above your system available" Is there something in the query plan that allowed you to determine this?  It is a plausible, but I'm not sure how you came to such a conclusion based on the information provided.